# rsync does not take into account --include-from setting

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I spent a lot of time to find a solution for my problem or find what am i doing wrong.
I would like to save my user home folder into another, mounted folder...so I thought, I am going to use rsync...but!
I have this include file:

```
+ /home/
+ /home/developer/
+ /home/developer/save_only_this_folder/*.*
+ /home/developer/.gitconfig
+ /home/developer/.kube
- *
```

So as you can see I would like to save some folders with contents and a file (.gitignore)
Command what i am using:

```
rsync -azhv --dry-run
--include-from=/home/developer/preparation/rsync_include.lst /home/developer/ /mnt/c/Work/WSL/save/ubuntu20.04/home
```

...and yes, I am using WSL.

The result: copy everything under /home/developer folder not only those what are listed in import file.

Question would be: what am I doing wrong?
Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Include/exclude patterns are matched *relative to the root of the transfer*, so you should not include "/home/developer" in the pattern paths. Also, since you're using WSL, make sure the include file has unix-style line endings, not Windows-style (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) for info).

Comment: Hello @GordonDavisson!
Thanks for your answer...you are right, this was the problem, now it is working perfectly!
May I ask to add your comment as an answer to accept it? Thanks!